# Best approch to reindex data every 2 weeks in CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm using cloudSearch to query 200k documents. The Database is updated every 2 weeks, so I need to import these new datas intho CloudSearch.

I want to avoid three things during and after an update :

- Impact on CloudSearch domain performances
- Inconsistency on the data during the update (for example if I have a field "city" and I decide to rename "NYC" in "New-York")
- No rollback available

To avoid all of that, I want to create a new domain each time. I will be able to rollback to another domain in case of major failure. I will keep only the 3 last domains (sanitary batch to manage).

Do you have any feedback ? Other advices ?

Thanks,
Romain.